# d3 classed() not working as expected with multiple classes?

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, sass

I've created the following scss definition:

```
.regionBackgroundHighlighter
{
    .highlight
    {
        fill:#CCCCCC;
        opacity:0.5;
        stroke:black;
        stroke-width:0;
        display:inline;
        visibility:visible;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set this css class to an element as follows but the style isn't getting applied:

```
d3.select(regionBackground).classed('regionBackgroundHighlighter highlight', true);
```

In Chrome Dev Tools, regionBackground shows both regionBackgroundHighlighter and highlight in its classList[] but the actual style isn't getting applied to the element. However if I pass the same class definition as one-level un-nested class then the style gets applied as expected:

```
.regionBackgroundHighlight
{
    fill:#CCCCCC;
    opacity:0.5;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:0;
    display:inline;
    visibility:visible;
}

d3.select(regionBackground).classed('regionBackgroundHighlight', true);
```

Do I need to use the d3 classed() function differently for the type of css structure I have defined in my first example above?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt scss works this way.

When you nest like above, 'highlight' style would be applied to any element having class as 'highlight' inside element with class 'regionBackgroundHighlighter'.

The structure u need for the above scss is:

```
<svg>
 <g class="regionBackgroundHighlighter">
  <g class="highlight">
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

@taran-j suggested how to fix markup to match your scss, other way round - fix your scss:

```
.regionBackgroundHighlighter
{
  &.highlight
  {
    fill:#CCCCCC;
    opacity:0.5;
    stroke:black;
    stroke-width:0;
    display:inline;
    visibility:visible;
  }
}
```

This will keep classes from nesting in compiled css.